# Solución a "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: DamoonPlay"

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy tratando de hacer un login, pero cuando presiono el boton "Iniciar Sesión", en terminal me figura "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: DamoonPlay". Ya probe actualizando la tabla, volviendo abrirla y de ninguna manera la lee. Paso a dejar el código por si tengo algo erroneo.

```
# Ventana Principal

def login():
    db = sqlite3.connect("DamoonPlay.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM DamoonPlay WHERE usuario=? AND clave=?', 
    (texto1.get(),texto2.get()))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row:
        messagebox.showinfo('Info','Inicio de sesión exitoso!')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Info','Inicio de sesión fallido!')

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Iniciar Sesión")
ventana.iconbitmap("Icono_tienda.ico")
ventana.resizable(0,0)
ventana.geometry("300x400")
PDV_DB = "DamoonPlay.db"

# LoginFrame
mainframe = Frame(ventana)
mainframe.pack()
mainframe.config(bg = "dodger blue", width = 300, height = 400)
# Input Usuario 
texto1 = Label(mainframe, fg = "white", bg = "dodger blue", text = 'Usuario', font = ("Roboto Thin", 15)).place(x = 115, y = 120)
texto1 = StringVar()
texto1.set("Ingrese su Usuario")
usuario = Entry(mainframe, bg = "snow2", textvariable = texto1 , state = 'normal')
usuario.place(x = 20, y = 155, width = "260", height = "40")
# Input Clave
texto2 = Label(mainframe, fg = "white", bg = "dodger blue", text = 'Clave', font = ("Roboto Thin", 15)).place(x = 120, y = 200)
texto2 = StringVar()
texto2.set("contraseña")
clave = Entry(mainframe, bg = "snow2", textvariable = texto2 , show = "*", state = 'normal')
clave.place(x = 20, y = 230, width = "260", height = "40")

# Botón Ingresar
btn_Ingresar = Button(mainframe, text = "Iniciar Sesión", bg = "pale turquoise", state = 'normal', command = lambda:login())
btn_Ingresar.config(font = ("Roboto Thin", 12), bd = 2, relief = "groove", borderwidth = 3, cursor = "hand2", justify = CENTER)
btn_Ingresar.place(x = 20, y = 280, width = "260", height = "40")
# Botón Registrar
btn_registrarse = Button(mainframe, text = "¿No tienes acceso? ¡Registrate!", state = 'normal')
btn_registrarse.config(font = ("Roboto Thin", 10), fg = "white",relief = "flat", borderwidth = 0, cursor = "hand2", bg = "dodger blue")
btn_registrarse.place(x = 55, y = 360)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Estas seguro de que la tabla existe? Recuerda que si eliminas el archivo y te vuelves a conectar, tendrás una base de datos sin tablas (ya que automáticamente vuelve a crear el archivo de cero). Por otro lado, quizá sqlite es case-sensitive. Eso significa que la tabla HolaMundo no es lo mismo que holamundo.

Comment: Si lo sabia, ya me habia pasado antes y lo pude resolver, ahora probé lo mismo y no puedo. Si puse exactamente el mismo nombre, y reemplace en los lugares pertinentes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar revisando la ruta

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Esta línea lo que hace es setear el punto de partida de búsqueda de ruta desde el script que se ejecuta, coloca la ruta a la base de datos desde el script que ejecutas. Debes importar la librería `os`